# Cucumber+Serenity "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below "

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, serenity-bdd

I have developed a test automation with serenity-bdd and cucumber for mobile testing. My problem is down below.

```
TEST PENDING: User can login with credentials
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "User launch the app" is undefined

cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "User sees the login page" is undefined

cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "User enters asdf@hotmail.com to username input" is undefined

cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "User enters 123123 to password input" is undefined

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (4 undefined)
0m0.837s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

**NECESSARY METHODS IMPLEMENTATION**
```

Although I have implemented this methods, I get this again.  My runner, cucumbersteps and feature file is like below.

Runner:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/", glue = "cucumbersteps")
public class EbebekRunner {

}
```

cucumbersteps:

```
class LoginSteps {

  @Steps
  EbebekLoginSteps ebebekLoginSteps;

  @Given("^User launch the app$")
  public void user_launch_the_app() {
    ebebekLoginSteps.launchApp();
  }

  @When("^User sees the login page$")
  public void user_sees_the_login_page() {
    ebebekLoginSteps.confirmLoginPage();
  }

  @Then("^User enters (.*) to username input$")
  public void user_enters_to_username_input(String userName) {
    ebebekLoginSteps.enterUserName(userName);
  }

  @And("^User enters (.*) to password input$")
  public void user_enters_to_password_input(String password) {
    ebebekLoginSteps.enterPassword(password);
  }

}
```

feature:

```
Feature: Login App

  Background:
    Given User launch the app

  Scenario Outline: User can login with credentials

    When User sees the login page
    Then User enters <username> to username input
    And User enters <password> to password input

    Examples:
      | username         | password |
      | asdf@hotmail.com | 123123   |
```

My Project Structure is as mentioned below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaogd.png)

I have tried to change glue as {"cucumbersteps"} but nothing is change.
I don't understand why problem is invoke. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this type of error is tricky and it could be happening for multiple reasons (*for example, having the runner, steps or features outside the test folder*), however, based in the info you shared, try adding the name of the feature file in the path:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/yourfile.feature",
        glue = "stepdefinitions")
```

In case you have a directory inside the step definition folder, you must do:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/yourfile.feature",
            glue = "stepdefinitions/your_directory")
```